# C - manipulating stdin or stdout

Tags: c, networking, stdout, stdin

im currently writing a simple chat program.
What I am trying to do, is to display your username in front of your chat messages (other people already have that from the server).
Now I see a few methods of doing this.
Either I block the output somehow (for example not outputting stdin or removing the last line from stdout) and let the server handle the username concat, or I manipulate stdin/stdout and prefix the line with my username on the clientside.
The problem is, I don't know how to do neither and googling isn't very helpful.

Heres the code snippet of the main loop:

```
while(1){
    //printf("while runs\n");
    readfds_buffer = readfds;

    rv = select(sockfd+1, &readfds_buffer, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (rv == -1) {
        perror("select");
    } else if (rv != 0) {
        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds_buffer)) {
            if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }

            //buf[numbytes-1] = '\n';
            buf[numbytes] = '\0';

           if (numbytes > 1) {
               printf("%s",buf);
           }
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(0, &readfds_buffer)) {
            if (fgets(str, 79, stdin) != NULL){
                send(sockfd, &str, sizeof(str), 0);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't mix unbuffered (file descriptors, `select`, etc) and buffered I/O (`FILE`, `fgets`, etc).

Comment: You do not want to suppress echoing the user's message as they type it.  That would be a usability nightmare; no chat program does it.  You could consider *prompting* the local user with a prompt that looks like the username the server will send.  Or with a generic prompt such as "me:".

Comment: OT: The loop misses to handle the case `recv()` returns `0` indicating the peer side shutdown the connection.

Comment: @melpomene what should I use instead to read out input?

Comment: John Bollinger that would be a way to do it, but not a very elegant one. is it really not possible to catch/manipulate stdin and stdout somehow?  
@alk isn't 0 the timeout indication?

Comment: Well, this would be kind of ignoring the overheating-alarm of your Porsche's engine, because it has an automatic fire-extinguisher built in ... :-/